# Laravel Static Model Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I want to save my picture and all the logic is inside my Model. But my model is always return `Trying to get a property of non object on line 80.`

Here is my code:

In UserController.php:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try{
    $user = new User($request->all());
    if($user->save()){
        User::savePicture($user->id, $request->cover);
    }
    DB::commit();
} catch(\Exception $e){
    DB::rollback();
}
```

In User.php (Model):

```
protected $picBaseDir = 'images/users/pic/';

public static function savePicture($id, UploadedFile $file)
{
    $user = static::find($id);

    $path = env('DIRECTORY') . $user->picBaseDir;
    makePath($path);

    // all other logic to move the image, etc
}
```

Line 80 is at `$path = env('DIRECTORY') . $user->picBaseDir;`

I've tried Log the id inside my model, it return correctly. But when I try log `$user` inside model it return empty.

Any solution?

Thanks

---

Found the solution. The culprit is my global scope inside user. It only check if the status is 1. When the user is saved, status is still 0.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to dd `$user` before `$path = env('DIRECTORY') . $user->picBaseDir;` this line?

Comment: I've tried it already. it return me null.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't find problems with your code, but I think that there is no reasons to use static function. Let your users save its pictures by itself.

```
// UserController.php

$user = new User($request->all());
if($user->save()){
    $user->savePicture($request->cover);
}

// User.php
protected $picBaseDir = 'images/users/pic/';

public function savePicture(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $path = env('DIRECTORY') . $this->picBaseDir;
    makePath($path);

    // all other logic to move the image, etc
}
```

Comment: I've tried to remove it but still return me same. I've update my question. I forget to put DB::beginTransaction on my question.

Answer (score -1):

```
// UserController.php

$user = new User($request->all());
if($user->save()){
    User::savePicture($user->id, $request->cover);
}

// User.php
protected $picBaseDir = 'images/users/pic/';

public static function savePicture($id, UploadedFile $file)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    $path = env('DIRECTORY') . $user->picBaseDir;
    makePath($path);

    // all other logic to move the image, etc
}
```

Comment: still give me trying to get a property of non object. I've update my question. I forget to put DB::beginTransaction on my question.